# What's the best practice when populating a sqlite database with default data?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, native

I'm making an app that will be using few hundred database posts from a sqlite database. I will not be adding new data during the lifetime of the app (unless I update the whole app).

I might end up using a static xml for the data, but I need to flag posts, so I guess a sqlite db would do the job best. I know how to implement it and I've released apps using sqlite before...

But my question is. How to I best populate the sqlite db the first time the app runs? Should I just bring in a file that I use as a resource and then copy to the apps space? What's the best/easiest practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). You basically drop your SQLite database into your project's `assets/` directory, and use `SQLiteAssetHelper` in lieu of `SQLiteOpenHelper`. In addition to the sample code up on Jeff Gilfelt's GitHub repo for the library, I have [a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsAssets) demonstrating it as well.

Comment: Super. So I can basically treat a sqlite db in my assets folder as any other? Can I write and read from it even if its embedded in my apk?

Comment: @Christoffer: "So I can basically treat a sqlite db in my assets folder as any other?" -- `SQLiteAssetHelper` will copy the database from `assets/` to internal storage, to a conventional spot for databases. "Can I write and read from it even if its embedded in my apk?" -- you can read and write the copy that is made in internal storage.

Comment: Ah. Cool. That's pretty much the solution I had in mind. great to get it confirmed. Thank you so much.